# Using option "resize" when making temporary layer into permanent shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a temporary layer I want to make permanent into a .shp file. In the settings, there is an option called resize. I can choose between yes and no.

What is the usecase of this option and when should I use "Yes"?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hover on top of the selection and you'll see a short context help text.

[image]

QGIS creates new fields by default wide so that attributes have enough space to fit in. When saving it is possible to analyze the attributes and shorten the fields and save some disk space because the .dbf part will be smaller. You can select YES if you know that there is no need to insert longer attributes with more numbers of longer strings in the future.